# How do I add a header to the contact form?

Tags: 7, emails

I want to add a text header to the core contact form (between the title and the "Name" field). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like [Rylyn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/7811/rylyn) said you can use the `#prefix` attribute. You could change your form with the `hook_form_alter`:

```
 function YOURTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // replace the 'FORM-ID' with the actual id of the contact form 
    if ($form_id == 'FORM-ID') {
       $form['name'] = array (
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => 'your_title',
          '#prefix' => 'your_text_header'
       );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "#prefix" attribute, like :

```
$form['name'] = array (
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'your_title',
     '#prefix' => 'your_text_header',
);
```

And "#suffix" is opposite.